# Twilio PHP conversation->message->read , could not sort using provided syntax

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-conversations

Here is the snippet of twilio doc for php to order messages

```
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$messages = $twilio->conversations->v1->conversations("CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                                      ->messages
                                      ->read(["order" => "desc"], 20);

foreach ($messages as $record) {
    print($record->sid);
}
```

[image]

Here is my implementation

```
$messages = $twilio_client->conversations->v1->conversations($conversation_channel_sid)
    ->messages->read(["order" => "desc"], 20);
```

but it was not allowed. it ran into following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Twilio\Rest\Conversations\V1\Conversation\MessageList::read() must be
> of the type int or null, array given, called in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\teleupachar2.0\P127_TeliUpachar\chat-module\conversation_test.php
> on line 67 and defined in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\teleupachar2.0\P127_TeliUpachar\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Rest\Conversations\V1\Conversation\MessageList.php:103
> Stack trace: #0
> D:\xampp\htdocs\teleupachar2.0\P127_TeliUpachar\chat-module\conversation_test.php(67):
> Twilio\Rest\Conversations\V1\Conversation\MessageList->read(Array, 20)
> #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\teleupachar2.0\P127_TeliUpachar\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Rest\Conversations\V1\Conversation\MessageList.php
> on line 103

it says it must be of the type int or null. Is there any other ways to filter or sort those messages?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. It appears that the docs are out of sync with the PHP library, as there are no sorting options in the PHP library. I have brought this up with the team internally to work out which is correct so we can update and get you unstuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It turns out that the order parameter is new. In fact it was only released a week ago. The helper libraries are generated every 2 weeks and the next time it will be generated with the latest API definitions is 25th August. In the meantime, the documentation got ahead of the library.

So, look out for the next version of the [Twilio PHP library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php), which should bring the order parameter to the messages resource list and make that example code work for you.

Comment: Hi evangelist, indeed,  the new update solved the issue. Thank You :).

Comment: Great news, and sorry you had an issue with this. We’re looking into how the docs and libraries can stay in sync.